# Haskell using Eq=> in function definitions

Tags: haskell

I have a function which contains an abstract data type as a parameter. In order for me to be able to equate this abstract data type I used:

```
myfunction:: Eq x=> [x]->[x]->[x]
```

So it takes in two lists of x, and outputs a list of [x]

However, when I call it from another function:

```
anotherfunction::[x] -> [x] -> [x]
anotherfunction a b = myfunction a b
```

it says

> No instance for (Eq x) arising from a use of myfunction, in the
>   expression myfunction a b

However, if I call myfunction from the console, with the two arguments it works fine.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Eq` in the type of `anotherfunction`.

```
anotherfunction::Eq x => [x] -> [x] -> [x]
anotherfunction a b = myfunction a b
```

`myfunction` works only with types that are in the `Eq` class. But your current definition of `anotherfunction` claims it can work with any type.  This would cause a problem if you called `anotherfunction` with a type that is *not* in the `Eq` class - it wouldn't be able to call `myfunction`.

Answer (score 2):

`myfunction:: Eq x=> [x]->[x]->[x]`

Here x has to have an instance declaration for Eq class.

```
anotherfunction::[x] -> [x] -> [x]
anotherfunction a b = myfunction a b
```

Here `myfunction` assumes type of `a` and `b` to belong to `Eq` class, but the type of `anotherfunction` makes no such constraint.

The correct way would be to specify this constraint in `anotherfunction` also.

```
anotherfunction:: Eq x => [x] -> [x] -> [x]
anotherfunction a b = myfunction a b
```

If you have any confusion, the easiest way would be not to give any type to `anotherfunction` 
and load the file in ghci and see what type is inferred for `anotherfunction`.

```
> :t anotherfunction 
anotherfunction :: Eq x => [x] -> [x] -> [x]
```

ghc will infer the most generic type so if you want type to be more specific then it is better to give explicit type for x. Like

```
anotherfunction :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

Here `Eq` instance for `Int` is already defined so you don't get any error. So If you assign the polymorphic type `x` to any specific type then you just need to make sure it has the instances for constrained classes.

Comment: "ghc will always infer the most generic type"... The "always" isn't quite true: the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MR) can get in the way in some situations (especially when defining things in GHCi, e.g. defining `anotherfunction` in GHCi as `let anotherfunction = myfunction` means that it has type `[()] -> [()] -> [()]`).